# All the functions are running immediatelly, how to run only the main function?

Tags: f#

I am learning F#, and have this code:
The problem is that all the functions are running immediatelly when I run the project. Coming from C#, I imagined that only the Main function would run. How to fix this? Is this some indentation question?

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms 

let form 
    = 
        new Form
            (
                Width = 400, 
                Height = 300, 
                //Visible = false, 
                Text = "Hello World F#"
            )

let MyFunction1 
    = 
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe")

let AnotherFunction 
    = 
        let agora = DateTime.Now
        let fn = @"C:\temp\testef.txt"
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText (fn, "Olá " + agora.ToString())
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", fn)


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv 
    =
        let f = form.ShowDialog()
        f |> Console.WriteLine
        0
```

[image]

Comment: What functions? To me it looks like you're defining some variables (an instance of `Form`, the return value of `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`, etc.).

Comment: Interestingly, that still seems to be the number one thing that trips F# beginners up. By the way, what's up with the = on their own lines? That is a very odd thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add at least one argument to the functions, otherwise they will be values that are not functions.

If you don't have anything to pass to the functions then they should receive a unit argument, for example here it should be:

```
let MyFunction1 ()
    = 
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe")
```

When the let binding has no arguments then it becomes a value and it's executed immediately.

The confusion when switching to functional programming is that in fact functions are also values, first class citizens that you can pass around, but in non-lazy languages like F# they only execute code when you supply their arguments at the call site.

Answer (score 2):

Your "Functions" don't accept any arguments, so they aren't really functions, they are just assignment statements.

```
let MyFunction1 = 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe")
```

Here `Process.Start` is executed and the return value is assigned to `MyFunction`. To fix this make your functions accept unit as an argument:

```
let MyFunction1 () = 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe")
```